# Formula to show specific database field Crystal

Tags: syntax, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Is there any way to set up a formula to display a value depending on the value in another field?

Say if new_field = -1 then display info in new_field2 of that data row? How would a formula for that work?

I've tried it now with doing a formula that just has
if{table.order} = 3 then {table.value} ...the value is a number...but it is just showing 0.0 each time while the value is showing up normally with the other records that display above when just dragging and dropping the database value field into my group. I'm trying to put this formula in the report footer to display additional information on one of the records.

Comment: What is the value of the formula for the last detail record in the report? I would expect this to be the same as the value of the formula in the report footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the footer, it is too late to display info on any single record in the report. They have all been processed and are gone by the time the footer is proocessed.

You could probably set up a global variable and set the value in a hidden formula in the detail section when the interesting record is processed. The use a formual to display the global variable value in the footer.

Comment: The first paragraph of this answer is incorrect. When the footer is printed, Crystal is still on the last record.

Answer (score 1):

Create a formula similar to the following:  @DisplayNote

Global stringvar xx;

if {db.field1.value} = 1 then xx:= "your text" else xx:= ""

Then create a running total formula: #DisplayText

Select the @DisplayNote formula as the field to summarize.
Type of summary = maximum

Then place the #DisplayText on the pagefooter.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the maximum of the formula value into the report footer, instead of the formula value itself.